# request help mapping horizontal complex square roots

Tags: complex-analysis

**Given** : 
$\;b\;$ is a **fixed** positive number, $\;\mathscr{D} \;\equiv\; \{ \,z \;: \;\text{Im}(z) = b \,\}, \;f(z) = \sqrt{z}.$

**To Do** : 
Compute $\;f(\mathscr{D})$.

**Context** 
This is a **portion of** problem 4.56(i) in chapter 1 of "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory" 
(1991, Bruce Palka), which I am self-studying for recreation.

In problem 4.54, I **was able** to prove that if $\;\mathscr{E}\;$ is any line that
passes through the origin and $\;g(z) = z^2\;$, then $\;g(\mathscr{E})\;$ is equal
to a ray whose slope will depend on the slope of $\;\mathscr{E}\;$.

However, although $\;\mathscr{D}\;$ could be construed to be the
*range* of $\;g,\;$ since $\;\mathscr{D}\;$ is a horizontal line, I have decided to **ignore** that $\;f = g^{-1}\;$ and attack
the problem from scratch.

**My Work** 
When I attacked the problem using the **generic** $\;z = x + i(b)\;$ I saw no
elegant simplification of $\;\sqrt{z}.$  Then I used graphing software and 
determined that $\;f(\mathscr{D})\;$ equals a curve that I have never seen 
before.

I noticed that in previous problems in chapter 1, Palka had referred
to the cardioid and the lemniscate, expressing each by an equation in polar
coordinates.  It therefore seemed as if this would be the best that I could do.

For $\;\theta \,\in (0, \pi/2),\;$ I can express a generic 
$\;z \,\in \,\mathscr{D}\;$ as 
$\;r^2e^{2i\theta},\;$ where $\;\frac{b}{r^2} = \sin(2\theta).$ 
This implies that $\;f(z) = \sqrt{z} = re^{i\theta}.$ 
Therefore, $\;f(\mathscr{D})\;$ maps to the polar equation
$\;r^2 = \frac{b}{sin(2\theta)}.$

**Is this accurate?**  If so, Is this the solution **that Palka intended?**

**Supplemental** 
I Intentionally presented a very narrow focus to my query.  Actually problem
4.56 involves horizontal lines and vertical lines, and indicates that a 
distinction must be made as to whether the horizontal or vertical line crosses
the negative real axis.

I mention this only because it may impact what you speculate to be the purpose
of problem 4.56.  In this query, all I am asking is: 
when $\;\mathscr{D} \;\equiv\; \{ \,z \;: \;\text{Im}(z) = b > 0 \,\},\;$
is my expression for $\;f(\mathscr{D})\;$ **what Palka intended?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z$ be on the line $x + i b$ and $w=\sqrt{z}$. We want $(\xi + i\eta )^2=x+ib$ in the $w$-plane.  This gives two equations:

$$\begin{aligned} \xi^2 - \eta^2 &= x, \\ 2\xi\eta &= b. \end{aligned}$$

Since $x$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, any point $w=(\xi,\eta)$ satisfies the first equation.

So the solution lies on the hyperbola $$\xi \eta = \frac{b}{2}.$$

If we want the principal branch of $w=\sqrt{z}$, then take that part of the hyperbola in the first quadrant:  $\xi>0, \eta>0$.

Comment: nice response. ...

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}$